# .write() Progressbar using tqdm is possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tqdm

Recently I had an idea for a script for encrypting/decrypting files in a selected folder, in which .write() plays a major role in writing encrypted/decrypted bytes to a file, and now I would like to add tracking of the progress of this very .write() like "76%|███████  |". I know that “tqdm” exists, but from the examples on the Internet there is only downloading a file with tracking the writing of content to a file, and can someone help remake a script for tracking the speed of writing to a file of content downloaded to a file, the structure of which I unfortunately understand I can’t (pbar = () args), in a script that will track exactly .writing() in the progressbar?

*tqdm example*

```
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm

url = 'https://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/2.1/WNsnsmap-2.1.tar.gz'
filename = url.split('/')[-1]
resp = requests.get(url,stream=True)
pbar = tqdm(desc=filename, total=int(resp.headers.get('content-length', 0)),unit='B', unit_scale=True, unit_divisor=1024,)

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    for data in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        f.write(data)
        pbar.update(len(data))
    
pbar.close()
```

*What i want to do*

```
#my block of code

for filefolder, dirs, files in walk(input_dir):
    for filename in files:

        pbar = tqdm(desc=filename, .?.)

        print(f"Encrypting {filename}..")
        try:
            with open(filefolder + "\\" + filename, 'rb') as encryptingfile:

                b85_bytes = b85encode(encryptingfile.read())

                output_file = open(filefolder + "\\" + filename, 'wb')
                output_file.write(b85_bytes)

                #pbar.update() equivalent, which displays the progress output_file.write(b85_bytes)

                output_file.close()

        except PermissionError:
            print(f"\rSkipping: {filename}\n")
```

I was trying to replace

`for data in resp.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):`

to

`for data in b85_value:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written several functions for this task for you. I hope it solves your problem

```
import os
import time
from tqdm import tqdm


def iter_files(folder):
    for root, _, files in os.walk(folder):
        for file in files:
            file = os.path.join(root, file)
            yield os.path.getsize(file), file


def iter_with_progress(folder):
    progress = tqdm(unit='B',
                    total=sum(s for s, _ in iter_files(folder)),
                    unit_scale=True,
                    unit_divisor=1024)

    for size, file in iter_files(folder):
        done = lambda: progress.update(size)
        yield done, size, file


for done, size, file in iter_with_progress('C:\Python311'):
    time.sleep(1)
    done() # Call done after encryption is complete
```

Comment: Great, it worked, thank you very much. Finally, I would like to ask a question: can this be used for example for b85encode or encryptingfile.read()?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. read the file within the final loop, perform the encryption operation, and then call "done" to update the progress bar.